# Find files whose path ends with certain pattern

Tags: c#, autohotkey

Given a file is in C drive, and its path ends with "Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\Fonts\GlobalMonospace.CompositeFont", what is the most efficient way to find the file?

It may be able to find, for example,  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\Fonts\GlobalMonospace.CompositeFont".

I can implement it in C# or AutoHotKey. I think [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383571(v=vs.100).aspx) and [loop](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm) directive will work, but what is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` with option `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to find all directories. Then pick those whose path ends in "Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\Fonts". Then for those, check whether the file "GlobalMonospace.CompositeFont" exists in those directories using `File.Exists`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Loop,  C:\*Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\Fonts\GlobalMonospace.CompositeFont, , 1  ; recurse into subfolders
{
    MsgBox, 4, , Filename = %A_LoopFileFullPath%
    continue?
    IfMsgBox, No
    break
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm